# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value when simple insert record

Tags: mysql

I want to simple insert into a table but have the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '" K "' 0.031 sec
```

I have searched it seem to be a type problem. But I don't think I am passing the wrong types here.
This is my insert command

```
INSERT INTO book (authors, book_id, title) VALUES (3, null, 'facebbok');
```

This the create table

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `isbn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_rating` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_text` text,
  `formt` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `authors` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_pages` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_month` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publication_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ratings_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`),
  KEY `authors` (`authors`),
  CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`authors`) REFERENCES `author` (`author_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`authors`) REFERENCES `author` (`author_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36485494 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: INSERT query itself is absolulely legal on shown structure. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b923ed89df73048b68ad8b6f71dd0e49 Look for triggers on this table. PS. The structure is wrong. Two contradictory constraints does not allow update or delete rows in `author` table.

Comment: @Akina it was a trigger problem. I have a duplicate constraint as well. thx